# Returning the address of a local variable and dynamically created variable

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, dangling-pointer

Code 1:

```
int *g(){
    int *p;
    p=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p=10;
    return p;
}
```

Code 2:

```
int *g(){
    int p=10;
    return &p;
}
```

OUTPUTS:

Code 2 ----> [Warning] function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
Still gives correct output(10)

Code 1 ----> Works fine. No warnings, no errors.

I have many questions.

1. Code 1 is also returning address of a local variable, so why no warning?
2. Code 2 gives warning, which I understand, that I am returning the address of a local variable. When the execution of function g is completed, the stack record is popped off and hence, there is a case of dangling pointers. Still, when I run it, why does it give correct output(10)?
3. Code 1 works with No warnings, no errors. But is it a good practice?

P.S the main function is same for both scenarios.

```
int main()
{
    int *v=g();
    printf("%d",*v);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: 1) Not the address but its value 2) Its undefined behavior so it might work might not 3) Its okay if you dont forget to free it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Code 1 is not returning address of a local variable but returning an address of a region allocated on the heap, so it is fine.
2. *Undefined behavior* is invoked and you got the result by chance.
3. The function `g` has two problems:

- You didn't check the result of `malloc()` while you should do so.
- Casting results of `malloc()` [is considered as a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: So in code 1, that  variable's storage is not in stack, but in heap? Thank you so much for clearing this detail up for me.

Comment: Normally, i always check the result of malloc, but this was a test code, so i didn't. 

And for casting the result of malloc(), this is entirely new information for me! In my university exams, I didn't put the (int *) typecast, and I got my marks deducted!

Comment: The variable `p` itself is on the stack. An address for heap is stored in the variable `p` and the stored address is returned.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for making it crystal clear now.